# How do I pair my Apple Keyboard with Apple Watch?

Tags: keyboard, apple-watch

Can I pair my keyboard to the watch? If so, how?

Comment: Why would You want to do it?   ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Actually a good question - if there's some app that could take input from the keyboard - perhaps there's another way to input data...

Comment: @bmike think about this problem this way - Your Apple Watch in order to work needs to be on Your wrist. If You use keyboard you need to use both hands, so You do not interact with Apple Watch when You type. It does not make sense to use keyboard simultaneously (IMO and UX piont of view).

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Forgive me for not being clearer - I think your comment was a good question to the OP. I wonder what they're up to with this question other than "can I give my fish a bicycle to ride?"

Comment: @bmike I apilogize, my answer could be a bit harsh - I misunderstood Your comment. Anyway I'm still curious why someone needs keyboard for Apple Watch.

Comment: Having used both the Samsung Gear and iWatch, I think a keyboard pairing would be useful. Whether using a handheld or desktop keyboard, the device(s) could be work in such a way on the wrist to allow you to see the screen whilst typing input. https://www.imore.com/why-i-want-keyboard-apple-watch

Comment: "why would you want to do it" is a good question if you're asking to help you give a better answer. If it's a rhetorical question meant to imply "that's a dumb thing to do" then not so much. Apple is moving the Watch away from complete dependence on a phone.  Accepting direct keyboard access is a very logical capability in my opinion, even though most people would never use it, and those that did would only use it in a pinch.

Answer (score 5):

You can't with any shipping keyboard in 2015 and Watch OS 1.0 or 2.0.

Apple Watch only pairs with iPhone, BT headphones, and BT heart rate monitors.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204218

Comment: any update now that we're on WatchOS 5? I assume nothing has changed, but...